# Getting duplicate calls for criteriabuilder relationship because of two gets

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I am getting duplicate calls because of the below code can anyone help with this. I am getting duplicates for the `Student` class which is there in the second get method mentioned below.

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CreateriaQuery<AccAssotio>cq= cb.createquery(AccAssotio.class);
cq.where(root.get(AccAssotio_To_SHR).get(Student_ID).in(?));
```

Comment: Might want to explain a bit more- what is duplicated exactly? it isn't clear what you are even selecting with this query, as we don't know what AccAssotio_To_SHR is or its relationship to the root (which is hopefully AccAssotio.class). JPA get forces inner joins by defaults, so my first guess is that you have a xToMany relationship where some have multiple AccAssotio_To_SHR with student ids in your list. Filter AccAssotio in memory locally, or look at using the distinct keyword/option in your query to have the DB do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship is defined as Lazy and you access the properties in chain, you can fire several queries to DB, try something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getSession.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<AccAssotio> cq = cb.createQuery(AccAssotio.class);

Root<AccAssotio> root = cq.from(AccAssotio.class);
Join<AccAssotio,Student> join = root.join(AccAssotio_To_SHR);

cq.where(joinStudent.get(Student_ID).in(?))
```